# Count of how many cast members have worked with other different actors/cast

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
title     |      cast 
------------------------------
movie1    |  cast1,cast2,cast3
movie2    |  cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7
movie3    |  cast4,cast3,cast5
```

---

```
pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['movie1','movie2','movie3'], 'cast': ['cast1,cast2,cast3','cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7','cast4,cast3,cast5']})
```

---

So, I want to get result something as :

```
cast   |      count
------------------------------
cast1  |  5 
cast2  |  2
cast3  |  4
cast4  |  5
cast5  |  2
cast6  |  3
cast7  |  3
```

To do that,

```
df_cast = df.join(df.cast
              .str.strip(',')
              .str.split(',',expand=True)
              .stack()
              .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
              .rename('cast_member')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This would add a new column `cast_member` with each cell having just one cast member name in it. I tried using `groupby('cast_member')` but, I am not sure how to proceed after that.

[image]

I am new to pandas so I would really appreciate an answer even though it could be a simple one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column with count per `movie` first:

```
df_cast['cast_count'] = df_cast.groupby('movie')['movie'].transform('size')
print (df_cast)
    movie                     cast cast_member   cast_count
0  movie1        cast1,cast2,cast3       cast1            3
1  movie1        cast1,cast2,cast3       cast2            3
2  movie1        cast1,cast2,cast3       cast3            3
3  movie2  cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7       cast4            4
4  movie2  cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7       cast1            4
5  movie2  cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7       cast6            4
6  movie2  cast4,cast1,cast6,cast7       cast7            4
7  movie3        cast4,cast3,cast5       cast4            3
8  movie3        cast4,cast3,cast5       cast3            3
9  movie3        cast4,cast3,cast5       cast5            3
```

Then aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) per `cast_count` and subtract for final `count`:

```
df = df_cast.groupby('cast_member')['cast_count'].agg(['size','sum'])
df1 = df['sum'].sub(df['size']).rename('count').reset_index()
print (df1)
  cast_member  count
0       cast1      5
1       cast2      2
2       cast3      4
3       cast4      5
4       cast5      2
5       cast6      3
6       cast7      3
```

Comment: Thanks :) . Would it make more sense if we use `cast_count` in place of `count_movie` , because although we are counting over `movie` but we are getting count of the cast members that are in that movie.